# Serialize C# object with two different JsonConverter using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

My use case requires me to serialize/ deserialize c# object for multiple clients, basically an internal client and external client.
My internal client simply uses the objects properties as a naming scheme for the json data. My external client has the exact same properties, but wants to have a different name for some of the properties. In this szenario my client wants the below `Customer` field to be renamed to `Mandant`. However it is crucial for me to be still able to serialize to `Customer` as a field name. Only in certain scenarios I need to be able to serialize for my external client. I am currently using `Newtonsoft.Json`

My C# class could look something like this:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public string Customer {get; set;}
}
```

My expectation would be that I could serialize/ deserialize in two different ways,
e.g. my external client wants the field `Customer` to be renamed to `Mandant`.

Serialize for internal client:

```json
{
   "Customer": "MyCustomer"
}
```

Serialize for external client:

```json
{
   "Mandant": "MyCustomer"
}
```

Comment: Create specific classes for the different clients, then map between the internal used classes and the classes for serialization and just serialize the correct class then.

Comment: What do you mean by map? I am more imagining a solution that could work with property attributes. I mean there is JsonProperty attribute, but this would change the name for both my internal and external client

Comment: Attributes are a more constant things defined at compile time. You want something that works at runtime (change behavior according to context). That does not fit. You may look  into writing your own custom ContractResolver to change property names according to that context. But the most clean (IMHO) is having distinct classes for distinct serializations and map between classes. That solution scales with new demands on changing fieldnames. If you change one field name for one customer the likelyhood is high that it does not end there.

Comment: There is another way to use dynamic 
"dynamic blogObject = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonData);"
But as ralf said, the cleanest way is separate classes

Answer (score 1):

Please distinguish between your internal business logic DTOs (or POCOs) and the data you publish to external systems (doesn't matter if it is a customer or another program / tool / library of yourself).

So let's assume you have some kind of data source (e.g. Sql DB, Cosmos DB, Redis cache, etc.). The used source normally has some kind of conventions on how the classes must be designed (Sql mostly has an Id property or follows some scheme to handle 1:many relationships; Cosmos needs a partition key; Redis needs some cache key; etc.). You should stick to these data source rules and model your objects to best fit the given source rules and your requirements (e.g. read optimized, write optimized, etc.).

In a next step define the DTOs on how they are presented to the other systems. Give them the properties and structure as required by the customer (this could be you too, but for another project in the same or another solution). Then write a converter / mapper that takes an object of type A and produces an object of type B (for this purpose you could take a look at *AutoMapper* to simplify the process). Also it makes sense to create different DTOs also for the same target type, but different operations (e.g. create / update).

All these steps need some effort, but in the long run it will be much easier to distinguish between the different operations and/or customers and prevent you from creating god classes which try to handle multiple things (e.g. customers) at once.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a custom ContractResolver

```
List<string[]> customerReplaces = new List<string[]> { 
                    new string[] { "Customer", "Mandant" } 
                   };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer,
                Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new ReplaceNamesContractResolver(customerReplaces)
                });

public class ReplaceNamesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly List<string[]> _replaces;

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {

        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        var newName = _replaces.Where(v => v[0] == property.PropertyName)
                               .FirstOrDefault()?[1];

        if (newName != null) property.PropertyName = newName;

        return property;
    }

    public ReplaceNamesContractResolver(List<string[]> replaces)
    {
        _replaces = replaces;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `JsonProperty` attribute from `Newtonsoft.Json` :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MyClass 
{ 
    [JsonProperty("Customer")]
    public string Customer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Mandant")]
    public string Mandant 
    { 
        get { return Customer; } 
        set { Customer = value; } 
    }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
var obj = new MyClass { Customer = "MyCustomer" };

var SerializedForInternalClient = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); // Output: {"Customer":"MyCustomer"}
var SerializedForExternalClient = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); // Output: {"mandant":"MyCustomer"}

var DeserializedForInternalClient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(SerializedForInternalClient); // Output: "MyCustomer"
var DeserializedForExternalClient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(SerializedForExternalClient); // Output: "MyCustomer"
```

Comment: the answer looks more of AI tool generated

Comment: That should work but will create JSON with both properties all the time. That might be OK or might not be. For  large object it may also increase data size significantly.

Comment: This will not pass the most code reviews as it violates SRP.

Comment: This is not what I want as it includes both properties for internal and external client. Isn't there a way to tell the deserializer at which attribute to look at? I could then create an InternalClient and ExternalClient property

Comment: will creating a custom JsonConverter help? @mathisplewa

Comment: @FatemehHasheminasab Yes that could help, but I got no experience with this. You got anything on hand? Is there a way to tell a JsonConverter at which Attribute to look?